# What are the difference between e.g. 想, 觉得 and 认为 when expressing opinion?

Tags: difference

What are the main ways to express opinion in Chinese? I know there are some verbs used for this, like 想, 觉得 and 认为. What are the difference between them when expressing opinion? (I know they also have alternative meanings but I am only interested when used to express an opinion or a thought.)

Comment: As a new community member, I'd like to understand why a question like this one would get downvoted. It seems well-formed and specific.

Comment: @alexsome precisely and according to [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language) the average of questions per day is 2.1 in this site and fewer than 5 "needs some work" (for being a healthy beta)... So downvoters, please refrain to shove away new members and actually try to answer their questions.

Comment: Yes, down-voters as a matter of courtesy should give reasons for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's the same as in English:

> 我想 - I think (that) xxxxxxxx
>   我相信 - I believe (that) xxxxxxx
>   我觉得 -
>   I feel (that) xxxxx

I will hold to explain how to use each of these in English as you should have an idea already.

Answer (score 2):

The three verbs have the quite the same meaning. Actually, you can use either of them as an equivalence.
If you are really keen to the difference.

```
想- just like, "I think" 
觉得 - I think things should be what I thought in mind, but not very sure
认为 - I believe things should be what I thought
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

想，觉得：一般比较随意，是日常交流的 (maybe colloquial; I'm not sure)

认为：通常比较正式，像正式的建议或者报告，表述自己的想法.

PS： 我是中国的. (I am Chinese.)

---

English translation of the above:

> 想，觉得: they're ordinarily based on one's wishes, as in everyday communication (maybe colloquial; I'm not sure).
>
> 认为: usually more official, like a formal proposal or report, precisely explains one's thoughts.