# Is there any difference between 想, 觉得 and 以为?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, past-tense

`想, 觉得，以为` all mean to think. But is there any subtle difference between the three or tense difference? When would you be more likely to use them in context?

Comment: users recommend;search site for Q&A about  **认为／以为** ，dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:  **想**  to think
to believe
to suppose
to wish
to want
to miss (feel wistful about the absence of sb or sth)，（思索） think; ponder:想办法 think of a way; try to find a solution 想问题 think over a problem（推测; 认为） suppose; reckon; consider; think:
你想会下雨吗? Do you think it will rain? **觉得**  to think
to feel（发生某种感觉） feel; be aware; sense:
一点不觉得累 not feel tired at all
（认为） think; feel; find:
我觉得不必事事都告诉他。 I don't think we have to tell him everything.
他觉得这个计划不妥当。 He felt the plan to be unwise.

Comment: Rather similar to [What are the difference between e.g. 想, 觉得 and 认为 when expressing opinion?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16041/what-are-the-difference-between-e-g-%e6%83%b3-%e8%a7%89%e5%be%97-and-%e8%ae%a4%e4%b8%ba-when-expressing-opinion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[我想 + statement] the statement is what I think is true

[我觉得 + statement] the statement is what I feel is true

[我以为  + statement] the statement is what I thought was true

[我認为  + statement] the statement is what I concluded to be true

[我相信  + statement] the statement is what I believe to be true

Examples:

我**想**他不会来了 = I **think** he won't come

我**觉得**他不会来了 = I think (**feel**) he won't come

我**以为**他不会来了 = I **thought** he wouldn't come

我**認为**他不会来了 = I think (**concluded**) he wouldn't come

我**相信**他不会来了 = I think (**believe**) he wouldn't come

Answer (score 2):

**以为** is mostly used for:

- wrongly thought/believed

like: `我以为你死了！` I thought you were dead!

**觉得** is closer to:

- feel/think (of an opinion)

like: `你这样说，我觉得非常不靠谱` What you said is totally unreasonable.

想 is close to the English:

- think

like: `我想这个案子肯定有猫腻。` There's something fishy about this case.

In Chinese the idea of English 'think' is hardly ever used - even in English it's mostly just a buffer or fluff; if anything 觉得 is the closest.

Comment: 想 is close to "to think about " in the English, and close to "miss". 以为 is mostly used for: wrongly thought/believed or a  modest mode. 以为 usually is used in writing.